# What’s wrong with this PNG Transparent image generator? The background is Black

Tags: php, image, png, transparent

First: I want to create a PNG image and draw a shape inside it.

Second: Overlap the first PNG on another image (for example a jpg image)
The problem is: When I create the first PNG with a shape inside (the background is not transparent and is dark) so this make a black overlap on second image.

How can I fix it?

I don’t work so much with images function so I got trouble.

**Notes:** I need to create the first transparent PNG and then overlap it on second image. I don’t want to create shape directly on second image.

***And The Code:***

```
<?php

    define('EXAMPLE_TMP_SERVERPATH', '');
    define('EXAMPLE_TMP_URLRELPATH', '');


    $tempDir = EXAMPLE_TMP_SERVERPATH;
    $fileName = 'test3img.png';


    $imgW = 125;
    $imgH = 125;

    # First
    $base_image = imagecreatetruecolor($imgW, $imgH);

    $black = imagecolorallocate($base_image, 0, 0, 0);
    imagecolortransparent($base_image, $black);
    $col[0] = imagecolortransparent($base_image, $black);

    imagealphablending($base_image, true);
    imagesavealpha($base_image, true);


    imagefill($base_image, 0, 0, $col[0]);

    imagefilledrectangle($base_image, 4, 4, 50, 25, 255);

    imagepng($base_image, $tempDir.$fileName);


# First2
$target_image = imagecreatetruecolor($imgW*5, $imgH*5);
$black2 = imagecolorallocatealpha($base_image, 0, 0, 0, 127); 
imagecolortransparent($target_image, $black2);

imagecopyresized($target_image, $base_image, 0, 0, 0, 0,$imgW, $imgH, $imgW, $imgH);
imagedestroy($base_image);
imagepng($target_image, $tempDir.$fileName);
imagedestroy($target_image);
# First2

    # Second    
    $dest = imagecreatefromjpeg('../avatar.jpg');
    $src = imagecreatefrompng(EXAMPLE_TMP_URLRELPATH.$fileName);


    imagealphablending($dest, true);
    imagesavealpha($dest, true);

    imagealphablending($src, true);

    imagecopyresampled(
                        $dest,
                        $src,
                        0,0,
                        0,0,
                        200, 200,
                        125, 125
                    ); 

    imagepng($dest, EXAMPLE_TMP_URLRELPATH.'_m.jpeg');

    imagedestroy($dest);
    imagedestroy($src);

?>
```

Comment: Also I want to make the shape transparent too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to add the alpha channel too:
[Alpha Channel](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocatealpha.php)

Comment: can you help me more please?

Comment: Change: $black = imagecolorallocate($base_image, 0, 0, 0); to: $black = imagecolorallocatealpha($base_image, 0, 0, 0, 127); Try that and get back to me.

Comment: that work for first code I add, but i forgot to add some part of code and add it as part first2. first one and second worked fine. but after first2 the second png is not transparent and is black

Comment: Glad I could help...sorry I passed out. Night shift sucks :) Glad you figured out the rest on your own.